# How to take in key input in c++ console for a CUI game

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a snake game with text, but I don't know if it's possible to take in key input in the console without using 3rd party libraries and want to know if it's possible, Thanks.

Comment: [FAQ on how to question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and [Make it Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why this aversion towards using a library? Not using a library just means you are going to reimplement the library yourself. Why waste your life on that when libraries already exist and can just be used right now..?

Answer (score 1):

The third-party libraries do it. They are written in C or C++. So yes, you can do it too.

But you don't say what operating system you're using. The methods are different between Windows and Unix.

In fact, if you want to be very pedantic, Unix terminals are not all VT102 and a real console UI will use terminal libraries like termcap to find the correct control sequences. There are literally hundreds of ancient terminal types. Every DEC, IBM, HP, Wyse or Tektronix did their own slightly different thing.